# Pointing SSL domain from Cloudflare to Azure Storage static website

Tags: azure

I have created an Azure Static website using azure storage account and then I have pointed CNAME record to the primary web link provided under the Static Website section in the Azure Storage account. My domain name is connected with Cloudflare to provide with SSL for my domain but even its SSL enable I get the error saying "This site is not secure" in the address bar padlock sign location. What is the reason to happen this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either need to add a custom hostname to the storage account or set a page rule in cloudflare that rewrites the host headers.